# Rails project located at port 8080 while nginx at port 80

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, puma

I have deployed my Rails app to VPS (DigitalOcean). I have installed NGINX that will handle all my static `css`, `js` and `html` files.

I have uploaded my project via capistrano.

When I open my page at `example.com` it shows me page **Welcome to NGINX**. I can only access to my pages by entering `example.com:8080/admin` and it does not load `css`, `js` and `html` files.

NGINX does not detect static files, which are generated by Rails.

What did I miss? Why I my rails app is on 8080 port?

My `nginx.conf` file is:

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///var/www/newsapp/shared/tmp/sockets/newsapp-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;

  root /var/www/newsapp/current/public;
  access_log /var/www/newsapp/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /var/www/newsapp/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
      gzip_static on;
      expires max;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
     location @puma {
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_redirect off;

     proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I'm using **Puma**. My `deploy.rb` file:

```
set :application, 'newsapp'
set :repo_url, 'https://example@bitbucket.org/example.git'
set :linked_dirs, %w(
   bin log vendor/bundle public/system
   tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets
)
set :puma_bind, "unix:///var/www/newsapp/shared/tmp/sockets/newsapp-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "/var/www/newsapp/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "/var/www/newsapp/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "/var/www/newsapp/shared/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "/var/www/newsapp/shared/log/puma.access.log"

namespace :deploy do

   after :restart, :clear_cache do
     on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
     # Here we can do anything such as:
     # within release_path do
     #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
     # end
     end
   end

end
```

My `config/deploy/production.rb`:

```
server "my.server.ip.here",
   :user => "deployer",
   :roles => %w(web app db)
```

My `nginx.conf` file located on VPS `/etc/nginx`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}
http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

There are a lot of lines which were commented. I have just skipped them.

My `var/log/nginx/error.log` has that kind of lines:

```
 2015/07/12 13:25:08 [emerg] 12215#0: open() "/var/www/newsapp/newsapp/current/log/nginx.access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Can you show your puma config as well?

Comment: You access to Puma via socket not by port. It seems you have multiple Nginx server blocks that shows it listens more than port 80. Please show whole Nginx config and make sure error_log is empty

Comment: @mikhailov Well this is my `nginx.conf` fle that is in my Rails project. You mean config that is located in my VPS?

Comment: @QQQ yes, we talk about server

Comment: server unix:///var/www/newsapp/shared/tmp/sockets/newsapp-puma.sock; is wrong...remove all extra forward slashes....and use /var/www/newsapp....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my `nginx.conf` I have changed my `upstream puma` to:

```
upstream puma {
   server 0.0.0.0:8080;
}
```

In my `config/deploy.rb` I needed to write this:

```
set :puma_bind, "0.0.0.0:8080"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you do not remove default page in site-enabled.

**rm -f /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

Next, your nginx access log open failed problem.

Try changing your log file path.

```
access_log /var/www/newsapp/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  # => /var/www/newsapp/shared/log/ACCESS_LOG_FILENAME.log
error_log /var/www/newsapp/current/log/nginx.error.log info;
  # => /var/www/newsapp/shared/log/ERROR_LOG_FILENAME.log
```

Maybe I think when nginx have started first, there is no current folder because current folder is generated when app is deployed.
And nginx is not restarted whenever deploying your app.
So try restarting nginx or modifying nginx log path to static path not symlink path. (**Don't forget** to restart nginx after modify conf file)

css, js not loading problem.

Did you execute assets:precompile while deploying ? 
Check if there is require 'capistrano/rails' in Capfile.
and then set your :rails_env in deploy.rb.

and deploy again!